# How can I make a space between every third number?

Tags: python

I have a list of numbers that looks like this when I run the code:

```
["1005637", "604976", "607574]
```

Is it possible to make a space between every third number, so it looks more like this:

```
["1 005 637", "604 976", "607 574"]
```

It looks a lot cleaner, but I don't know if the numbers is still considered like its no space in between.

Comment: if you try `int("1 100")` you will get an error, so no, it's not considered a number anymore. But you could do `"1 100".replace(" ", "")`, but  I bet there is some kind of library that has `fancy_format("1100") == "1 100"` truthy, and it can convert it back and forth

Comment: Check PEP 515: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0515/ - Underscores in Numeric Literals - separator is different, but it solves the same problem

Comment: I wonder what is the context of your question, because this is more a display issue and this kind of operation should not be done within the program where you will need to manipulate these data

Comment: I wanted that way of writing the numbers, because I want to annotate the number above each bars in a bar chart like that. I thought it would work if I defined the list like that, but maybe not :(

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
lst = ["1005637", "604976", "607574"]
res = [f"{int(val):,}".replace(",", " ") for val in lst]
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
['1 005 637', '604 976', '607 574']
```

Although I suggest, you use `"_"` (underscore) as a separator, to keep the string as an int literal, as below:

```
lst = ["1005637", "604976", "607574"]
res = [f"{int(val):_}" for val in lst]
print([int(e) for e in res])
```

**Output**

```
[1005637, 604976, 607574]
```

**Additional**

- [PEP 515](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0515/) as suggested by @Lesiak in the comments.